# Twitter Bootstrap carousel previous link throws error, carousel caption shifts after sliding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to incorporate my first bootstrap carousel because I want my site to look just like everyone else's. (jk). Inside the carousel at present is the standard "Hero" box you see in basic bootstrap examples.

I am having two issues, and while I assume they are user error I cannot see cause of the issues.

Here's an example: 
http://bootply.com/69097

Issue 1) when the carousel is "sliding" the caption starts out lower, and then snaps up into place when it's done.

Issue 2) This is probably more important that #1. The Next button works fine, but the Previous button throws an error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'previous' of object # is not a function.

Thanks for any feedback.

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to abbreviate your previous code -

```
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#landingpagecarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
```

I am trying to figure out why it is pushing the content down, give me a few on that one.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I copied that from a tutorial, maybe it was a typo.

In this case I don't actually *need* the caption, but it would be nice to know for future reference.

Comment: Yeah taking a look at it I think it is something not being cleared in the CSS until it has transitioned but I am still looking.  If this helps hit up the answer button : P  Looking for that 1k mark to be cleared.

Comment: ok sure thing. :) I probably won't live long enough to hit 1k.